# r: Only keep data between certain patterns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains rows with lots of data that I do not need.

I only want to keep data that is between {type:.....]]],

Below is an example of what a row of my data looks like.

In the row below I have two occurrences of data that is between {type:...]]],
so ideally afterwards I would have {type:polygon:......6941736.81823727]]]{type:polygon:...6941544.531338006]]]

A row of my data looks like this:

```
structure(list(Id = "55", Area = "[{type:polygon,rings: 
[[[113387.82961770154,6941736.81823727],[113090.44180455463,6941640.077623354], 
[112992.50686207252,6941667.547180392],[112993.70119063937,6941778.61973711], 
[113088.05314742093,6941772.648094275],[113082.08150458665,6941843.1134797195], 
[113373.49767489928,6941840.724822586],[113373.49767489928,6941841.919151153],[113387.82961770154,6941736.81823727]]],_ring:0,spatialReference:{wkid:102100,latestWkid:3857},cache:{_extent:{xmin:112992.50686207252,ymin:6941640.077623354,xmax:113387.82961770154,ymax:6941843.1134797195,spatialReference:{wkid:102100,latestWkid:3857}},_partwise:null}},{type:polygon,rings:[[[113386.63528913469,6941544.531338006],[113316.16990369024,6941530.199395204],[113313.78124655654,6941568.417909343],[113381.85797486728,6941575.583880744],[113386.63528913469,6941544.531338006]]],_ring:0,spatialReference:{wkid:102100,latestWkid:3857,_geVersion:{fo:,mi:102100,Sl:null}}"), row.names = 2L, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this using `stri_extract` from `stringi`:

```
dat <- structure(list(Id = "55", Area = "[{type:polygon,rings: [[[113387.82961770154,6941736.81823727],[113090.44180455463,6941640.077623354], [112992.50686207252,6941667.547180392],[112993.70119063937,6941778.61973711], [113088.05314742093,6941772.648094275],[113082.08150458665,6941843.1134797195], [113373.49767489928,6941840.724822586],[113373.49767489928,6941841.919151153],[113387.82961770154,6941736.81823727]]],_ring:0,spatialReference:{wkid:102100,latestWkid:3857},cache:{_extent:{xmin:112992.50686207252,ymin:6941640.077623354,xmax:113387.82961770154,ymax:6941843.1134797195,spatialReference:{wkid:102100,latestWkid:3857}},_partwise:null}},{type:polygon,rings:[[[113386.63528913469,6941544.531338006],[113316.16990369024,6941530.199395204],[113313.78124655654,6941568.417909343],[113381.85797486728,6941575.583880744],[113386.63528913469,6941544.531338006]]],_ring:0,spatialReference:{wkid:102100,latestWkid:3857,_geVersion:{fo:,mi:102100,Sl:null}}"), row.names = 2L, class = "data.frame")
library(stringi)
dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate(area = stri_extract_all(Area, regex="\\{type:.*?]]]")) %>% 
  unnest(area) %>% 
  select(-Area)
dat
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   Id    area                                                                                                 
#   <chr> <chr>                                                                                                
# 1 55    {type:polygon,rings: [[[113387.82961770154,6941736.81823727],[113090.44180455463,6941640.077623354],…
# 2 55    {type:polygon,rings:[[[113386.63528913469,6941544.531338006],[113316.16990369024,6941530.199395204],…
```

Comment: But I also need it to keep the second occurrence of data that is between {type: and ]]]

Comment: Actually this has left the second occurrence of data between {type: and ]]] but not kept the first

Comment: I updated the answer.  There were new line characters in there that were making it so the regex wasn't finding the first instance.  Assuming you're going to have a continuous string with newline characters in it, this should work.  If you do have the new line characters, put this in the mutate before the one currently there: `Area = str_replace_all(Area, "\\n", " "),`